# jpeg2000 uses wavelet transform that works on tile , what if tile is small

Tags: jpeg, jpeg2000

I read that wavelet transform works on image as whole so no blocking artifacts ,
while JPEG does DCT on blocks of image so there is .
If we have 1024x1024 image and take tiles of 128x128 , then won't wavelet transform be applied independently on each tile ?
It is okay if we say wavelet transform used in jpeg2000 give better output than DCT transform of JPEG for given target file size.
But blocking artifacts will always appear if tile is small compared to image size , isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the DWT is applied to each tile independently, and a small tile size will introduce blocking artifacts.